# How to launch multi-threads in MPI + openmp?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi, openmp, eigen

I want to launch an OpenMP multi-thread region in one process within my MPI application code. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using namespace Eigen;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int rank, num_process;
    MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Ones(8, 4);
    MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Zero(8, 4);
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_process);
    MPI_Status status;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        int i, j, bnum = 2, brow = 4, thid;
        #pragma omp parallel shared(A, B) private(i, j, brow, bnum, thid) num_threads(2)
        for (i = 0; i < brow; i ++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j ++)
            {
                thid = omp_get_thread_num(); 
                //cout << "thid " << thid << endl;
                B(thid * brow+i,j) = A(thid*brow+i, j);
            }
        }
        cout << "IN rank 0" << endl;
        cout << B << endl;
        cout << "IN rank 0" << endl;
        MPI_Send(B.data(), 32, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Recv(B.data(), 32, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        cout << "IN rank 1" << endl;
        cout << B << endl;
        cout << "IN rank 1" << endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

In my example code, I want to launch 2 threads to copy data from matrix A to matrix B, and my machine has 4 cores. But when run the program, the matrix B has only got half the data.

```
$ mpirun -n 2 ./shareMem
IN rank 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
IN rank 0
IN rank 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
IN rank 1

$ mpirun -n 4 ./shareMem # it just hang on and doesn't exit
IN rank 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
IN rank 0
IN rank 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
IN rank 1
```

And the output I expected is

```
$ mpirun -n 2 ./shareMem # it just hang on and doesn't exit
IN rank 0
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
IN rank 0
IN rank 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
IN rank 1
```

How can I fix it and make 2 threads run in my code? Thank you!

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you better. For instance, MatrixXd is not defined anywhere. Also, which is the expected output you want? How does it differ from what you get? And how do you know that 2 threads are not running?

Comment: @Harald, MatrixXd is from include file <Eigen/Dense>, it is matrix class. I have edited the question

Comment: Sorry Alexander, but where does that header come from? I don't have it in my system, for instance.

Comment: @Harald, you can use 2D double array instead. Eigen is a matrix library https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(A, B) private(i, j, brow, bnum, thid) num_threads(2)
```

to

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(A, B) private(i, j, thid) num_threads(2)
```

`brow`, `bnum` are shared variables.
By adding names `bnum` and `brow` to private clause you are making new auto variables with such names for each thread and by default they are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the word parallel that the compiler doesn't catch.

`#pragma omp prallel`

PS: I don't have enough reputation to add a comment

Comment: thank you, but after changed it to `parallel`, I even got all zeros? What is wrong with my code?